# Attach ScrollViewer To FrameworkElement?

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, frameworkelement

Is it possible, using an `Adorner` or other means, to dynamically take a `UIElement/FrameworkElement` and place it within a dynamically created `ScrollViwer`?  I know that the obvious problem will be that you have to detach the element from it's parent element first, but I am looking for an elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If your element doesn't have to be interactive you can just use a `VisualBrush`. If it has to actually move from one place to the other and keep working as usual you'll have to either duplicate your control or attach/detach it.

To my knowledge there's no "elegant" way of doing this - you'll have to go through normal means, such as `Children.Remove/Add` (if its parent is a panel), etc.